# How to add string to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Example:

`var imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [46.773941, -79.12544]];`

I need to create same from js. The problem that I am getting data in string format:

`[40.712216, -74.22655], [46.773941, -79.12544]`

so:

`var mystr = "[40.712216, -74.22655], [46.773941, -79.12544]"`

Ok, lets create empty array:

`var myarr = []; // empty array`

but how to add data to it? I know about `push` method but it's work only with arrays, and I have got text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it valid JSON (by adding `[` at beginning and `]` at ending) afterward parse the string using **[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** method.

```js
var mystr = "[40.712216, -74.22655], [46.773941, -79.12544]";

var res = JSON.parse('[' + mystr + ']');

console.log(res);
```